# instead of select table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-view

Is there any way, in a trigger kind of way, to create a view instead of a table without dropping modifying the said table, ie:

```
create table t1(id int);
go
create table t2(id int);
go

create view tv as select id from t1 union all select id from t2;
go
```

Now do something in order that if i:

```
select * from t1;
go
```

I get the output of:

```
select * from tv;
go
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: This may work: `CREATE SYNONYM t1 FOR tv;` (not sure whether it will allow you to override an existing name).

Comment: @juergend I'm a strange person, that's way :P

Comment: @KlasLindbäck i get error `There is already an object named 't1' in the database.` when i try to create the SYNONYM, i guess this cannot be done, which is acceptable has my premise is pretty dumb :P

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be needing that.

If you are concerned about differences of your views and your underlying tables, then you should schemabind your views. That way your table can't be modified in the way it clashes with view definition. In addition, you can't use `SELECT *` in a schemabound view.

However, if you want to play with automatic view refreshing, here's the idea:

```
CREATE VIEW tv
AS 
SELECT * FROM dbo.t1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM dbo.t2
GO

CREATE TRIGGER alterView
ON DATABASE 
FOR ALTER_TABLE
AS 
    EXEC sp_refreshview 'tv'
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.t1 ADD txt nvarchar(18)
ALTER TABLE dbo.t2 ADD txt nvarchar(18)
```

However, you will notice that it's not possible to do alter in the first place, because it would break the 'equal number of expressions' rule for the view.

*EDIT*

I could have missed the point because I maybe didn't understand the question.
If you want to alias, you can use [SYNONYMS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx). If combined with schema, you can use them to alias a view:

```
CREATE SCHEMA TEST 
GO

CREATE SYNONYM TEST.t1 FOR dbo.tv
GO

SELECT * FROM TEST.t1
GO
```

If your focus is on the syntax, you will notice that new t1 aliased view is prefixed woth the schema. However, if you wrap that with procedure, you can loose the prefix and data will be selected from your aliased view.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST.TestProc
AS
    SELECT * FROM t1
```

Comment: i don't get this, if i do `select * from t1`, i still only get records from t1, what i would want is to get the records from t1 and t2 (view tv), the schema of the tables will not change.

Comment: i get error `There is already an object named 't1' in the database.` when i try to create the SYNONYM, i guess this cannot be done, which is acceptable has my premise is pretty dumb :P

Comment: Well, it depends how you look at it. let's say that you have to use a large procedure for reporting, don't have time to analyze it and have to append a bunch of data to one of the tables used in query. And must not break the schema. This could be one way to do it.

Comment: Ok, with schema no error, but i really need is to change the output of `select * from dbo.t1` without changing the table, so the schema solution would not do much.

The problem might be that i can't control what does selects from t1, but want to change what they get, temporarily, i think i'll just use   sp_rename

Comment: Can you wrap your select with the procedure?

Comment: Nope, can't even control what and how it selects :P